# How to set up Avalon docking manager to resize like VS?

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I am using Avalon in my WPF app.  I want a window similar to that of Visual Studio, Tools on the left, then the documents in the middle and the Properties on the right.  I managed to do that with this code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ad="clr-namespace:AvalonDock;assembly=AvalonDock"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="Window1" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ad:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
            <ad:ResizingPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <ad:ResizingPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <ad:DockablePane>
                        <ad:DockableContent Title="Toolbox" Width="100">
                            <TextBox />
                        </ad:DockableContent>
                    </ad:DockablePane>
                    <ad:DocumentPane x:Name="documentsHost" OverridesDefaultStyle="True">
                        <ad:DocumentContent Title="File1.doc">
                            <RichTextBox/>
                        </ad:DocumentContent >
                        <ad:DocumentContent Title="File2.doc">
                            <RichTextBox/>
                        </ad:DocumentContent >
                    </ad:DocumentPane>
                    <ad:DockablePane>
                        <ad:DockableContent Title="Project Explorer">
                            <TextBox />
                        </ad:DockableContent>
                    </ad:DockablePane>
                </ad:ResizingPanel>
                <ad:DockablePane>
                    <ad:DockableContent Title="Output">
                        <TextBox />
                    </ad:DockableContent>
                </ad:DockablePane>
            </ad:ResizingPanel>
        </ad:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem is that when I resize any of them, they all resize to keep their proportion.  This is not what I want, I want it to be like VS where just the document window in the middle resizes with.

I would appreciate any help since I have been fighting with this for a few days now :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny, because I started with the Avalon Tutorial from [there](http://www.youdev.net/post/2008/09/25/AvalonDock-Tutorial.aspx) and replaced the contents for the window with your XAML (very similar by the way). And the problem you describe does not happen.

Then I realized that the tutorial uses AvalonDock 1.1.1692, while the latest release is 1.1.2691 and has the behaviour you describe.

A look at the source code shows an attached property defined by ResizingPanel called ResizeWidth, which is 1* by default => the auto resize.

If you change the first DockablePane like this:

```
<ad:DockablePane ad:ResizingPanel.ResizeWidth="100" >
```

You get the behaviour you wanted.

It's never great to use hard-coded widths, so I changed it to

```
<ad:DockablePane ad:ResizingPanel.ResizeWidth="{Binding ElementName=dc, Path=Width}" >
```

after naming the inner DockableContent *dc*